# Detect If workbook has Worksheet, Avoiding error message in log

Tags: java, excel, exception, microsoft-graph-api

I have a piece of code in java using the microsoft graphapi, i need to detect if a workbook has a worksheet with the name "centralData", but it is working but placing some errors in the log

```
    try {
        WorkbookWorksheetRequestBuilder worksheetReq = workbookreq.worksheets("centralData");
        WorkbookWorksheet worksheet = worksheetReq.buildRequest().get();
        if (worksheet != null) {
            return true;
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return false;
```

even when i catch the exception i when this code run i get this message in the log

```
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ItemNotFound
Error message: The requested resource doesn't exist.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/<driveId>/items/<itemId>/workbook/worksheets/fundamental
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.46.0


404 : Not Found
[...]
```

i want to avoid this in my log because if its not there i know its going to fail but my exception catching is not working